# Looking for DTLS non-blocking program example (C/C++)

Tags: openssl, dtls

I am learning to use SSL & UDP. After some extensive search, I couldn't find many sample programs to test and study. In fact, the only one I found is this.

http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/DTLS-examples-td2143.html

However, although the author claimed it is non-blocking, after reading the code I don't think it is what we usually mean because it does not use select() or poll() at all. Would like to have some help here, really appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the code samples I found

[dtls samples](https://web.archive.org/web/20150814081716/http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/dtls-samples.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: `It's not just you! sctp.fh-muenster.de looks down from here.` The link should be replaced with `https://web.archive.org/web/20150814081716/http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/dtls-samples.html`