# Can someone share me sample code for securing UDP connection by using DTLS protocol?

Tags: server, udp, client, dtls

I have code where normal server n client are communicating but i need DTLS implementation to secure it , please help me out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking for DTLS non-blocking program example (C/C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168423/looking-for-dtls-non-blocking-program-example-c-c). The answer there is not specific to non-blocking but contains links to several examples. Also, do your own research first since such examples are [easy to find using a search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=dtls+example+code).

Comment: Maybe you add a hint for the programming language as well as the domain, you want to use DTLS? C/Java/...? IoT, video stream, ...?

Comment: yes I want in c++ language.Please help me in that.